# Change font size and color of all child elements

Tags: reactjs, react-native

With react native, I want to change the font size and color of all child elements.

I tried this but it does not work :

```
<View style={styles.last_post}>
    <Text>
        Blablabla
    </Text>
    <Text>
        Blablabla
    </Text>
    <Text>
        Blablabla
    </Text>
</View>


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    ...
    last_post: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        color: '#495057',
        fontSize: 12,
    },
    ...
})
```

Comment: pass it directly to text `<Text style={styles.titleText}></Text>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting style in the view , try puttingin every text element :

```
<View style={styles.text_post}>
    <Text style={styles.last_post}>
        Blablabla
    </Text>
    <Text style={styles.last_post}>
        Blablabla
    </Text>
    <Text style={styles.last_post}>
        Blablabla
    </Text>
</View>


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    ...
    last_post: {
        color: '#495057',
        fontSize: 12,
    },
    text_post:{
     flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
}


    ...
})
```

So here you are creating a global css style and applying to every text element. You change at one place and its done for all.